# Not able to open jupyter notebook on my Windows10 system using anaconda navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I am trying to open Jupyter notebook on my windows 10 system using anaconda navigator but not able to open it as it is showing following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kaushiki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
import sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kaushiki\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\kaushiki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 85, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\kaushiki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Have you tried installing the missing packages?
I.e. by running ```conda install sqlite3```

Comment: Yes tried to install sqlite3 but still issue not resolved